# Angular - class not applied when data comes from parent

Tags: angular

I am trying to add class 'active' to element that was selected from the list. The problem is that when I try to get the data form parent component, 'active' class is not applied. I guess it's more clear here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-okkrbd?file=src/app/child/child.component.html

I think it may be something with template refreshing(?). At this point I am not quite sure what to do. Tried many thinks but nothing helped.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` at initialisation of your app is not a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property includes doesn't seems to work for objects. I suggest you to use `some` instead. Like this

**ts**

```
tesCar(car){
  return this.selectedCarList.some(object => object.id == car.id && object.title == car.title)
}
```

**html**

```
[ngClass]="{'active': testCar(car)}"
```

This way it should work

***EDIT :***

If you got bigger object with the need of the entire object to be equal, you could use this to check if the values are good

```
this.selectedCarList.some(object => Object.values(object).every(item => Object.values(car).includes(item)))
```

This will iterate over each value of the object found on `selectedCarList` and check if the value is includes into the values of your car. This is better if you got a big object because you will not have to manually write `object.id && object.title && ...`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change the method `ngOnChanges` like this:

```
ngOnChanges() {
   this.selectedCarList = [];    
   if (this.dataToChild)
   {
      this.dataToChild.forEach(e => { 
         var wantedItem =this.carList.find(x => x.id === e.id);
         if (wantedItem)
             this.selectedCarList.push(wantedItem);
       })    
   }
 }
```

The problem is that items that you were adding in `this.selectedCarList.push` are different objects than the ones from your `carList` list. They have a different `hash` and that is why your filter `selectedCarList.includes(car)` always failed.